# How to prove $n=\sum_{d\mid n}\phi (d)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How to prove this equation is true?

$$n=\sum_{d\mid n}\phi (d)$$

Where $\phi(d)$ is the Euler's totient function.

Comment: Prove it for prime powers (elementary), and use the multiplicativity.

Comment: There are about a hundred copies of this question on MSE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** show that $f(n)=\sum\limits_{d\mid n}\phi(d)$ is multiplicative, then prove that $f(p^k)=p^k$ for prime $p$.

Answer (score 7):

Consider the fractions $\dfrac{1}{n}, \dfrac{2}{n}, \ldots, \dfrac{n}{n}$, and reduce them. There are exactly $\phi(d)$ of them with denominator $d$, where $d|n$. So the number of fractions is $\sum_{d|n}\phi(d)$. But it is also $n$, so $\sum_{d|n}\phi(d) = n$.

Comment: What does direct access mean?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the set $A = \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. Now consider the subset $A_d = \{k: (k,n)=d, 1 \leq k \leq n\}$, where $d \vert n$.

**Claim $1$**: $A_d$ forms a partition of $A$. (Why?)

Hence, we have $\sum_{d \vert n} \vert A_d \vert = n$.

**Claim $2$**: $\left\vert A_d \right \vert = \phi(n/d)$. (Why?)

> $(k,d) = 1 \iff (k/d, n/d) = 1$. Hence, number of such $k$ is $\phi(n/d)$.

Now conclude what you want.