# Difficulty understanding the proof that $n=\sum_{d|n} \phi(d) $

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-number-theory, finite-groups

I  am  reading  the  proof of  $$n = \sum_{d|n} \phi(d) $$  where  $n$  is  any  positive  integer  and  $\phi$  is  the  Euler's  $\phi$  function .

Now  the  proof  goes  on  like  this .

An  arbitrary   group  $G$  of  order  $n$ is  taken  and  the  equivalence  relation  is  introduced  as  follows $$x\equiv y \ \ \  \iff\ \ \ (x) = (y)$$  where  $(x)$  is  the  cyclic  group  generated  by  $x$  and  denote  by  $G(x)$  the  equivalence  class  of  $x$. Then  $G$  is  the  disjoint  union  $$G = \cup_{x\ in G} G(x)$$

Then $$n = |G| = \sum |G(x)| $$ Up to  this is  alright.  I  don't  understand  what  they  did  after  this.  Next they  simply write  "If  $G$  has  order  $n$ , then  counting  gives  $n = \sum |G(x)| = \sum_{d|n} \phi (d)$  where  the  summation  ranges  over  all  cyclic  groups  of  $G$, while  if  $G$  is  cyclic  then this  result  is  obtained  from  the  lemma 'A finite cyclic  group  $G$   has  a  unique  subgroup  of  order  of  every  divisor  of $|G|$ '  "

Please  help  me  with  explanation  of  this  last  segment  of  the  proof.

Thanks.

Comment: That's a lot of words.  Is there a particular part of what they wrote that you don't understand?  Or are you more confused about why this leads to the conclusion?  Are you familiar with the lemma?

Comment: The disjoint union symbol is being abused here. The union only becomes disjoint if you throw away repeated entries.

Comment: @ErickWong  :  I  clearly  mentioned  which  part  I  do  not  understand ; the  part  within  the  double quotes, the whole  of  that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/752396), and possibly many others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we need to prove: $|G(x)| = \phi(d)$, whereas $d = o(x)$, i.e $x^d = e$, and $d$ is the order of $x$ in $G$, and by definition of $|G(x)| = |\{y\in G: \exists k,  0\leq k \leq d, y = x^k\}|=|\{k: 0 \leq k \leq d, (k,d) = 1\}| =\phi(d) \Rightarrow |G(x)|= \phi(d) $, thus we're done.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might help to take a concrete group and work through what the $G(x)'s$ are explicitly.

Slightly offtopic:

Another proof I like is : Look at the set $\{\frac kn | 1\leq k \leq n\}$ and group the elements by what their denominators are in reduced form.